# Assigning a jQuery progressbar value from SQL using jQuery/C# Asynchronously

Tags: c#, jquery, multithreading, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I have a SQL server that does a back-end function that updates a field on a table with progress-percentage. I would like to efficiently update the value of the progressbar dynamically.

The webpage is a C# .aspx page and the progressbar is created using jQuery-UI.

What is the best method for doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order you update the progress bar in real time you have to make asynchronous calls to the server to check the data.  This is done using AJAX.  There are many ways to do it using AJAX (ex. JS code, AJAXControlToolkit, etc).  You'll have to decide which is the best option for you.

AJAX Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

ASP.NET AJAX Tutorials: http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/ajax/

AJAXControlToolkit: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

AJAX w/ jQuery: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/